# Does "the city" in Hebrews 11:10 refer to heaven?

Tags: hebrews, abraham

In Hebrews 11:8-10, the author refers to Abraham's faith. [In the ESV:](https://www.esv.org/Hebrews+11/)

> 8 By faith Abraham obeyed when he was called to go out to a place that
> he was to receive as an inheritance. And he went out, not knowing
> where he was going.
> 9 By faith he went to live in the land of promise,
> as in a foreign land, living in tents with Isaac and Jacob, heirs with
> him of the same promise. 10 For he was looking forward to the city
> that has foundations, whose designer and builder is God.

**Does "the city" in verse 10 refer to heaven?**

This same "city" seems to be referred to in Hebrews chapter 13 as well. [In the ESV:](https://www.esv.org/Hebrews+13/)

> 14 For here we have no lasting city, but we seek the city that is to
> come.

**Is there a connection between the "city" in Hebrews 11:10 and the "city" in Hebrews 13:14?**

Answer (score 3):

The question is answered explicitly in Heb 11:16 -

> Instead, they were longing for a better country, a **heavenly one**.
> Therefore God is not ashamed to be called their **God**, for He **has
> prepared a city** for them.

This same idea is again referenced in Heb 12:22, 23 -

> Instead, you have come to Mount Zion, to the city of the living God,
> the heavenly Jerusalem. You have come to myriads of angels in joyful
> assembly, to the congregation of the firstborn, enrolled in heaven.
> You have come to God the Judge of all, to the spirits of the righteous
> made perfect

The book of Revelation also alludes to the same idea in -

> Rev 21:10 - And he carried me away in the Spirit to a mountain great
> and high, and showed me the Holy City, Jerusalem, coming down out of
> heaven from God.

> Rev 21:2 - I saw the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of
> heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her
> husband.

> Rev 3:12 - I will write on them the name of my God and the name of the
> city of my God, the new Jerusalem, which is coming down out of heaven
> from my God

Jesus also alluded to this idea in John 14:1-3

> “Do not let your hearts be troubled. You believe in God;a believe in
> Me as well. In My Father’s house are many rooms. If it were not so,
> would I have told you that I am going there to prepare a place for
> you? And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come back and
> welcome you into My presence, so that you also may be where I am.